# How to get pam_succeed_if.so on OSX Sierra or later

Tags: macos, pam

i want to use pam_succeed_if in my pam configuration on OSX Sierra.
However, looking into /user/libs/pam shows that pam_if_succeed.so is missing.

(
this one:
https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_succeed_if
)

Where or how can i get that Module?

Comment: What's wrong with using the `pam` modules that come with `OS X`?

Comment: I need to skip a certain authorization under some circumstances. And OSX doesn't seem to have the specific module pam_succeed_if